# How much power do I need to power my daisy chain

Tags: guitar-effects

How to calculate how strong a power supply is sufficient? Do I need to have a  supply that equals the power consumption of all the effects, even though I will never turn on all of them at the same time?

Comment: If I'm not  mistaken, the effects say how much power they need (either on the box or on the site), so you can calculate it

Comment: @Shevliaskovic The power consumption  provided by spec say only how much it needs when turned on. The static power consumption is much lower but not speced

Comment: At the risk of getting a little technical, electrical power is the voltage times the current, and it's not so simple as having "enough power". The voltage must **match**, or else the pedal won't work right or might be damaged, and the total current supplied by the power supply must be **equal to or greater than** the current needed by all the pedals added together, as Tim's answer specifies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some, if not all of the pedals, will be sucking power even when they're not turned on, but merely plugged in with the guitar. Your best bet is to sum up the milliamps (1/1000 of an amp) and get a psu that covers this figure. You may want to consider the future, when you have extra pedals, too. Going over with the current is not a problem - voltages and polarity might be.

Comment: 100% concur with this - always budget for the total assuming all on, because then worst case you have some headroom. And who knows, you may someday decide to have all your effects on at once!